# How to convert csv to xlsx with openpyxl to any column?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv, openpyxl

I am creating code for converting csv to xlsx but my code has a problem, it can convert the values only to A1 column. How to make code to be can writing values from csv to any selected column?

```
import csv
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.active

with open('text.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=':')
    for row in reader:
        ws.append(row)

wb.save('file.xlsx')
```

Comment: Could you please share a minimal reproducible example of the issue that you are having, please. E.g. What is your specific input and how does the output look.

Comment: Of course, when I run this example everything works fine, but the values are only written to column A1, when I try to use ws['B4'] or ws['C8'], the values are just written to row 4 or 8 respectively, however not are written to the desired column and remain on column A

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the first few rows of your CSV file (copy / pasted in text format from a text editor)

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a comma (`,`) not `:` for delimiter.

I just tested this code and it made a perfect xlsx file with seperated columns.

```
import csv
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.active

with open('text.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',') # changed to ,
    for row in reader:
        ws.append(row)

wb.save('file.xlsx')
```

## text.csv

```
a,b
1,2
3,4
```

## file.xlsx

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use `open()`?

You can use pandas to open and save files:

```
pd.read_csv('text.csv').to_excel('file.xlsx')
```

Comment: Yes, but that wasn't the question asked.

Comment: Perhaps OP was looking for a way to convert csv into excel but made it more elaborate in his own solution, and was looking to fix his problem encountered in that (elaborate) solution, like an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Possibly, but there are advantages (chiefly filtering, memory) in going directly from CSV to XLSX without using Pandas.