# CSV sent using Flask's send_file() loses the BOM which makes the UTF8 chars in it Excel compatible

Tags: python, rest, csv, flask, utf-8

I'm working on a Flask backend using REST API that generates a csv report. The data in the report can contain special characters, which because of Excel's weirdness means that you need to encode the csv with `utf-8-sig` encoding (otherwise Excel uses `cp1252` (?) encoding and special characters aren't displayed properly).

I'm sure I generate the csv correctly since if I write it to a local file using Python it opens in Excel as expected. Same goes for zipping it (taking a `BytesIO` object and creating a new `BytesIO` object out of it using Python's `zipfile` library) and providing it to the client as a zip file.

However, if I return the `BytesIO` object directly using Flask's `send_file()` function, the BOM is lost and special chars aren't displayed properly in Excel. I'm not sure if it's caused by the `send_file` itself (I've tried drilling down in the implementation but I didn't see anything that could cause this) or by the browser (it happens with both Google Chrome and Firefox), but it's an issue.

Do you have any ideas how to work around this? I would like to provide a csv file that can be opened in Excel by double clicking it and it displays all of the characters properly. The code in question is provided below. Thanks!

```
response.seek(0)
filename = f'report {datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S")}'
response = BytesIO(response.read().encode("utf-8-sig"))  # add BOM to make Excel happy
response.seek(0)
return send_file(response, download_name=f'{filename}.csv', as_attachment=True, mimetype="content-type: text/csv; charset=utf-8")
```

---

**EDIT:** Using Postman I have determined that the BOM is scrapped by the browsers. The file is provided correctly by the backend and is then modified while being saved by the browser.

Comment: BOM is removed from `response` using `utf-8-sig` encoding in `response.read().encode("utf-8-sig")`…

Comment: @JosefZ I'm not sure what you mean, could you please elaborate so I can investigate further? `response` is a StringIO object and `response.read()` returns a `String` which is then encoded using `utf-8-sig`. This line IMO works correctly, since as I said, if I take the response after that line, zip it using `zipfile.ZipFile().writestr()` and send that as a response, the csv inside of the zip works correctly.

Comment: @JosefZ Encoding in utf-8-sig adds the BOM. Decoding removes it.

Comment: Why not create a real Excel file ? `Excel uses cp1252 (?)` that's incorrect. It uses the user's locale settings for non-Unicode text.

Comment: `the BOM is scrapped by the browsers.` actually it's the `mimetype` that tells browsers to treat the body as text and save it as as UTF-8 without a BOM. If you use `application/octet-stream` instead, the browser won't modify anything

Comment: `Excel's weirdness` not really. Without a BOM how would even a *human* guess what the actual encoding is, without actually loading the entire file? What if the non-US characters appeared at the very end? What if the data contained UK English words like `naïve` or `Brontë` at position 123000?

Comment: I disagree. Other than Excel, all software I've tried (including LibreOffice) displays the characters properly even without BOM, making this an Excel specific weirdness. I also disagree that the issue is caused by the application itself. The issue is caused by the fact that arguably the most common program to open csv files requires them to start with BOM to display special characters properly, while the http protocol doesn't support downloads of UTF-8 encoded text files with keeping BOM intact.

Comment: @Nonanon let me guess - never had to work with files from a different language or using a different codepage from your own? If you only work with Latin1 you'll never realize that other programs have issues with Cyrillic or Nordic text. As for CSV - that's just text with commas. How do you know *what* encoding is used in that text file with commas? Even on your Mac or Linux, you either check the BOM or use the LC_ALL codepage. And if the file encoding doesn't match your settings, you'll get garbage.

Comment: Your own Python programs could easily run into the same problem because [open uses the current locale encoding by default](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open): `The default encoding is platform dependent (whatever locale.getencoding() returns)`. There are a *lot* of SO questions from people who tried to use `open` without specifying a codepage and got `UnicodeDecodeError' exceptions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution! You need to include the BOM characters twice since the first set is removed by the browsers because that's how the spec specifies the UTF8 encoded file should be processed... This technically makes your csv file invalid, however, it is Excel compatible after being downloaded through a browser.

More info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42717677/9682679

Code modified as described above:

```
response = BytesIO(b"\xEF\xBB\xBF" + response.read().encode("utf-8-sig"))  # add BOM twice to fool the browser and make Excel happy
```

**EDIT:** Another workaround was provided by @PanagiotisKanavos. You can also use `octet-stream` mime type instead of `text/csv`. In that case the web browser has no idea it's working with a text file and therefore doesn't touch it. The resulting code reads like this:

```
return send_file(response, download_name=f'{filename}.csv', as_attachment=True, mimetype="application/octet-stream")
```

Comment: That's no solution. If you intend to use the file in Excel, why not create an actual Excel file with openpyxl?

Comment: In fact, the problem is *caused* by application itself through the mimetype, not the browsers. The application tells browsers to strip the BOM by specifying `charset=utf-8`. If you used `application/octet-stream` the browser wouldn't modify anything

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks, the `octet-stream` also works. The question is, which of those two workarounds is cleaner/what are the risks of each? The intended mimetype for a csv file is `text/csv` therefore using `octet-stream` isn't really clean either. A clean solution would be to use `charset=utf-8-sig` parameter, however, that isn't a [MIME defined charset](https://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets/character-sets.xhtml).

Comment: The two options are `octet-stream` or openpyxl. If you want to generate a file for use with Excel, use openpyxl. [with just 5 lines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71045898/134204) you can convert your CSV to Excel. The resulting file is actually *smaller* than a CSV. If you use Pandas you can write to Excel directly without going through CSV. If you want a CSV file that can be imported into other systems *and* loaded into Excel, use `applicatino/octet-stream`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks! For the purposes of this project I'll use `application/octet-stream`, but your advice might be useful for future reference. I'll edit the answer before I mark it as accepted.